# What is the per batch size limit of Algolia operations

Tags: php, algolia

I can see that the per record limit for Algolia records is 10kb: https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/basics/is-there-a-size-limit-for-my-index-records/

I am not sure though what is the limit per batch operation? The recommendation is 1,000 or 10,000 records but what size limit:

https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/indexing/import-synchronize-data/php/#batching

The above URL mentions that for Enterprise customers the limit is 1GB, what about non-Enterprise customers? What is their batch size limit?

Answer (score 0):

We recommend to send batches around 10MB depending of the bandwidth of your server.

Increasing the size to more than this value won't really increase the speed of indexing because the batch is already big enough to reduce the overhead of the HTTP request and the round trip time.